# Difference between / when to use methods over meteor skeletons

Tags: meteor

Looking at the Vue/Meteor tutorial both the property methods and meteor are used within the export default. I'm wondering what the difference is and when to use one or the other.

```
export default {
   methods : {},
   meteor: {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `methods` is from Vue itself, you can use it to define functions as methods to reuse and call them on your templates.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

The property `meteor` is from vue-meteor-tracker, a package created to integrate Meteor and Vue (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-meteor-tracker). You should use it when you are using Meteor reactive sources like cursors. Basically, with the `meteor` property, you can subscribe to publications and fetch data.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    handleSubmit(event) {
      if (this.newTask.length === 0) return;
      Meteor.call('tasks.insert', this.newTask.trim());
    }
  },
  meteor: {
    $subscribe: {
      'allTasks': []
    },
    tasks () {
      return Tasks.find({}, {
        sort: {date: -1}
      })
    },
  }
})
```

I suggest you have a look at this page from the tutorial and if you haven't already, follow the tutorial from the beginning.
https://vue-tutorial.meteor.com/simple-todos/09-publications.html

Comment: I see! I didn't get to that point yet, but now I played around with it a bit and it is clear, I got things running. Docs can be misleading sometimes ;-) Thanks!